# Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message support for Azure Webjob Service

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-webjobs, azureservicebus

I'm developing my application on .net core framework which uses the following code to push messages to queue which is to be received by a webjob.

```
topicClient = new TopicClient(connection)
Message message = new Message(utf8encodedtext)
await topicClient.SendAsync(message);
```

BrokeredMessage support(Microsoft.ServiceBus namespace) is not yet there for .net core. I'm using the following code for Webjob

```
public static void   ProcessQueueMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("topicgeneric","subscription")] BrokeredMessage message, TextWriter log)
    {
        log.WriteLine(message.Label);

    }
}
```

With this setup I'm able to receive messages. However the web job doesn't support Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message. **Is there any workaround to use Messages instead of BrokeredMessage are there any tradeoffs/compatibility issue/data loss**. **I want to re-write my webjob in .net core framework. Will it still work (currently its written in .net framework) as Microsoft.ServiceBus nuget is not supported in .net core**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebJobs SDK version 2.x is using the old service bus client  with `BrokeredMessage` class.

WebJobs SDK version 3.x is using the new .NET Standard service bus client (`Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` with `Message` class). It's still in preview though, `3.0.0-beta4` is the last release is of today.

So, you'd have to pick the matching versions: either use all old or all new.

> BrokeredMessage support(Microsoft.ServiceBus namespace) is not yet there for .net core

`BrokeredMessage` will never appear in the new SDK, it's been replaced by `Message`. They are not compatible to each other, so various issues are possible.

Comment: _so various issues are possible_ The only major issue is wire compatibility. Messages coming from mixed senders (old and new) and receivers having the need to distinguish between the senders to know how to process incoming messages, serialized or not (stream based).